# How can I convert HtmlText to a normal string in c#

Tags: c#, json

I have the following model:

```
namespace power.Storage.Models
{
    public class Answer
    { 
        public HtmlText[] Explanation { get; set; }
        public string[] ImageFile { get; set; }
    }

    public class HtmlText { 
        [AllowHtml]
        public string TextWithHtml { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Now I want to be able to take the data from answer and do the following:

```
String[] _code_explanation = null;
_code_explanation = 
 (string) JSON.FromJSONString<Answer>(_code.AnswersJSON).Explanation;
```

But it's not working. It says "can't convert HtmlText to string

Is there something I'm missing? I thought all I would need to do was to add (string) before the JSON...

Here's the code for JSON

```
    public static T FromJSONString<T>(this string obj)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(obj)))
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            T ret = (T)ser.ReadObject(stream);
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

The following half works:

```
HtmlText[] _code_explanation = null;
    _code_explanation = 
     (string) JSON.FromJSONString<Answer>(_code.AnswersJSON).Explanation;
```

It gives me an array of HtmlText but then I am not sure how to convert this into a simple array of strings.

Comment: I do not know the answer to this particular question, but usually you do not cast to string, instead you call the .ToString() method `JSON.FromJSONString<Answer>(_code.AnswersJSON).Explanation.ToString();` might work?

Comment: What implementation of JSON is this?

Comment: The .ToString() seems like it might work but the problem is that The ouput is an array. What I need is an ToStringArray :-(

Answer (score 2):

`HTMLText` does not have a cast operator to `String`, explicit or implicit.

Answer (score 1):

You can decode HtmlText with with the [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332855%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) method. It cannot be directly cast to a string.

Comment: But where can I put this? First I have to put the data into an array of something and what I am getting back is an array of HtmlText

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this assuming teh Explanation is of type HtmlText

```
String[] _code_explanation = null;
_code_explanation = 
   JSON.FromJSONString<Answer (_code.AnswersJSON).Explanation.TextWithHtml;
```